# Regex that matches every bitstream without 5 following characters

Tags: regex

I need a Regex which matches every bitstream where no 5 following bits occur.
For example:

```
010001111 -> matches
010011111 -> does not match
```

I was able to create a Regex for a length that can be divided by 5.

```
((0|1){4}(?!\2)(0|1))+
```

Is there a way to do it without a length of multiples of 5?

Comment: Like [`^(?!.*([01])\1{4})[01]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/eO9sM6/1)? Or [`\b(?![01]*([01])\1{4})[01]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eO9sM6/2)?

Comment: This is probably better suited to more bitwise operators than regex, what are you doing that requires parsing raw bits using string tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data as text contents, and the bit chunks are split with space, you may use

```
\b(?![01]*([01])\1{4})[01]+\b
```

to match only those that do not contain 5 identical bits on end.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO9sM6/2)

**Explanation**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?![01]*([01])\1{4})` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if there are any 5 zeros or ones after zero or more ones or twos
- `[01]+` - one or more zeros or ones
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

For testing standalone bit chunks:

```
^(?![01]*([01])\1{4})[01]+$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO9sM6/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the bit, and count its occurrences:

```
>>> len(re.findall('(?=(1))', '010001111'))
5
>>> len(re.findall('(?=(1))', '010011111'))
6
>>> len(re.findall('(?=(1))', '010110111'))
6
```